# Is it allowed to use a different tile provider while using the Google Maps SDK?

Tags: google-maps, google, license

I would like to use a tile provider different than Google, while using the Google Maps SDK for everything else. Essentially, I want to use the `getTileUrl` function to provide a tile URL coming from a different source, for example OpenStreetMap.

This would leave me with using Google Maps SDK for drawing shapes onto the map, but would use (for example) OpenStreetMap for the tile images.

Is it allowed to use the Google Maps SDK while swapping the tiles to come from a provider other than Google?

I've gone through the [Google Maps TOS](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms) and I couldn't find anything explicitly forbidding this. I've also asked on the [Google Maps support forum](https://support.google.com/maps/thread/185651316/is-it-allowed-to-use-a-tile-provider-different-than-google-maps?msgid=185758496#), where they directed me here.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of search provides this, which technically covers what you ask for as far as I understand it:
https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Google_Maps_Example

With regards to terms of service, you will need to check specifically based on which services you are using, as restrictions may come at play (in particular using the Directions API)
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation